# Wordpress tax_query not showing private posts

Tags: php, wordpress

When querying posts with the following:

```
$getClientsArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'client',
    'showposts' => -1
);
query_posts($getClientsArgs);
```

Private posts are displayed if the person viewing is signed in.
Else, it skips that post and proceeds to show any non-private posts.

This is how I expected it to work.

But, when I start using tax_query, private posts are not shown to either people logged in or logged out. They are not returned at all.

See this example:

```
$getClientsArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'client',
    'showposts' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'client_types',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $clientType->term_id
        )
    )
);

query_posts($getClientsArgs);
```

**EDIT:**

---

Further inspection it seems that, when its not the code above causing the problem.
See comment on line 3.
Its this code:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'type'         => 'client',
        'hide_empty'   => 0, //Setting this to 1 will cause the issue explained above
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'taxonomy'     => 'client_types'
    );

    $clientTypes = get_categories($args);
?>
<?php foreach ($clientTypes as $clientType): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $clientType->name; ?></h2>
    <div class="main clearfix">
        <ul class="image-list">
            <?php
                $getClientsArgs = array(
                    'post_type' => 'client',
                    'showposts' => -1,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'client_types',
                            'field'    => 'term_id',
                            'terms'    => $clientType->term_id
                        )
                    )
                );

                query_posts($getClientsArgs);
            ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                    <?php $workLink = get_field('linked_project'); ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($workLink[0]); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php the_field('logo'); ?>" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile;
                wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the query to show the private posts. By default, only public posts are pulled through.

Try this

```
$getClientsArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'client',
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'private');
    'showposts' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'client_types',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $clientType->term_id
        )
    )
);

query_posts($getClientsArgs);
```

You can also add any other form of post status.

These are the available options

```
publish
pending    
draft
auto-draft
future
private
inherit
trash
```